# What is equivalent of .gdbinit file for dbx?

Tags: gdb, migration, dbx

I can have an initialization file in my home directory called .gdbinit which is run each time I start a gdb session to customize my environment.

What is the equivalent file name in dbx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ~/.dbxrc

The .dbxinit is an older obsoleted name for the file that will be used if .dbxrc is missing.